# My raspbian buster is stuck at Splash Screen with polkit.service!

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-buster, services, troubleshooting, crash

I was working fine with my Rpi4 this morning. Next time when I started it was okay. Then there was some resolution issue. so I went into raspi-config and disabled the OpenGL.  After a restart my PC is stuck at Splash screen. I know that reflashing the card would work just fine but I do not want to lose any file. What should I do now?

Comment: Restore from your backup

Comment: I couldn't make any.

Comment: Build a new card and use an SD card reader in the Pi to copy the files over?

Comment: Add these in the answer please